# Rewriting of SQL query without Row_Number so that It could be mapped to Hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle

Schema:

- `Table A`: AID(PK), RECEIVE_DATE
- `Table B`: BID(PK), AID(FK), MESSAGE, ITEMID, ITEMTYPE

Tables A-to-B have a one-to-many mapping.

Here is a working SQL query (in SQL Server) to find out the latest message grouped by ITEMID i.e for different ITEMID (of ITEMTYPE say as 'XYZ').

```
SELECT 
    result.MESSAGE, result.ITEMID 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.ITEMID ORDER BY A.RECEIVE_DATE desc) AS rn 
    FROM
        A 
    JOIN 
        B ON A.AID = B.AID
    WHERE
        B.OBJREFTYPE = 'XYZ' 
        AND B.SUBJECT IS NOT NULL) result 
WHERE 
    result.rn = 1
```

Is it possible to rewrite this query without using `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Above Query is working in SQL server, but I need to execute it in both SQL server and ORACLE without ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: That query won't work in Oracle because Oracle doesn't support `AS` for table aliases (although it does for column aliases).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: can you throw us the create script and insert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use something like this:

```
SELECT 
    b.MESSAGE, b.ITEMID
from a
inner join b on b.aid = a.aid
where a.receive_date in (select max(receive_date)
                                            from a a1
                                            inner join b b1 on b1.aid = a1.aid   
                                            where b1.itemid = b.itemid
                                            );
```